# Implementing Source Control with A Network Storage Check-In Location

Tags: version-control, tfs, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

Let me start by explaining the basic background for the scenario I am in.

I need to implement a source control solution for the web-development company that I am working for.  Our current development model is a shared network location for all files on a windows server, running IIS7 against the data drive, and no source control.  The network location is backed up very well, but this is obviously not a good setup (so please don't bother replying if you are only here to flame the lack of source control... that's the problem I am trying to solve)

I am looking to get a source control solution in place (playing with Team Foundation Server 2012 Express) but this is not going to be an instant process.  We have hundreds of sites, and this solution will not be rolled out for all of them overnight.  We also have many procedures in place that will need to be modified, which takes time, so I am looking for a solution that can be rolled out a little bit at a time.

My main question is, is it possible to get a source control solution in place that will allow my team to develop locally in VS2010, but check the files in to the existing network location?

The network location is our Development Server where changes are approved by project managers and clients before being pushed to production. Changing that process would seriously hurt my chances of being able to put a source control solution in place at all. (obviously that is not good)

I am attempting to set this model up in TFS2012 Express, but I can't seem to find any information on how to do that. The main repo is working as it should; I'm able to branch, merge, ... as expected, but I have no idea how to force all checked in files to be pushed to the network folder.  (I may be searching for the wrong terms)

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

I am not completely tied to TFS, but it is what I am most familiar with, and we are in a windows environment with several designers that are not command line experts. The solution I put in place must be easy for them to use, which means integration into Visual Studio.

Again, please don't turn this into yet another source control rant page.  There are far too many of those as is.  I am genuinely looking for a solution to the problem I'm facing, and I need to make the introduction of source control as smooth as possible or there is a very real chance that it simply wont happen... and that is bad for everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware TFS stores all the source code in SQL DBs. A hint from me would be to take a
look into [customizing TFS Build Configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400710%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I'm not 100% sure but it should be possible to add a task to a Build Configuration where you copy all files from the TFS workspace to your network storage. So whenever someone checks source code into the TFS you can let the TFS trigger a CI-Build which undertakes the necessary copy task.